# Function with variable number of arguments - C

Tags: c

**UPDATED:**

I have the following function with variable number of arguments that returns the address of a (directed unweighted) graph which has the largest *degree* among `n` graphs. One argument of the function is the number of graphs for input, `n`. Optional arguments are `n` pointers to those graphs.

**Note**: *Maximum degree* of a directed graph is the total number of *in-degree* and *out-degree edges* of a vertex that has the largest number of edges, with loops counted twice.

The following program doesn't respond:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct
{
    int n;//number of vertices in a graph
    void* info[MAX];//information in a vertex
    int am[MAX][MAX];//adjacency matrix
}GH;

int degree(GH *g)
{
    int i,j;
    int deg_row[MAX]={0},deg_column[MAX]={0};
    int count_row[MAX]={0},count_column[MAX]={0};
    int max=0,maxDeg,temp,count_total[MAX]={0};
    int transpose[MAX][MAX];

    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<g->n;j++)
        {
            transpose[i][j]=g->am[j][i];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<g->n;j++)
        {
            if(transpose[i][j]!=0)
                deg_column[i]++;
            if(i==j)
            {
                if(transpose[i][j]!=0)
                    deg_column[i]=deg_column[j];
            }
        }

        count_column[i]=deg_column[i];
    }

        for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<g->n;j++)
        {
            if(g->am[i][j]!=0)
                deg_row[i]++;
        }

        count_row[i]=deg_row[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        count_total[i]=count_row[i]+count_column[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        if(count_total[i]>count_total[max])
            max=i;
    }

    maxDeg=count_total[max];
    return maxDeg;
}

GH *f(int n,...)
{
    GH *deg;
    int i,j,maxDeg[MAX]={0},max=0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args,n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       maxDeg[i]=degree(va_arg(args,GH*));
       if(maxDeg[i]>maxDeg[max])
       {
            max=i;
            break;
       }
    }
    deg=va_arg(args,GH*);

    va_end(args);
    return deg;
}

void printGraph(GH *g)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("%d",g->n);
    printf("%s",g->info);
    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++,printf("\n"))
       for(j=0;j<g->n;j++)
          printf(" %2d",g->am[i][j]);
}

int main()
{
    GH gh1 = {4,{'1','2','3','4'},{{0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}}};
    GH gh2 = {4,{'1','2','3','4'},{{1,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,1}}};

    GH* res=f(2,gh1,gh2);
    printGraph(res);

    return 0;
}
```

How to print data about a graph that has the largest degree?

Comment: So, you're asking how to use printf?

Comment: @2501 I don't know how to pass the address of a graph with the largest degree and print it's data.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the variable arguments with (a pointer to the first element of) an array?

Comment: Do you know how to printf a single integer or floating point value?

Comment: Your second use of `va_arg()` is wrong ... you've already stepped through all the arguments in the for-loop.  I think you'll need to reset `args` (with another call to `va_start()`) and then step through `max` calls to `va_args()` to get the value to return (or -- as may be better -- not make the function have a variable number of arguments, but accept an array of `GH*` and return the index of the maximum).

Comment: First things first: This doesn't even compile since `deg_row[MAX]={0})` (and friends) isn't a variable definition. The call to `f()` looks very C++ to me (extended initializer list), but even then I get "*cannot pass initializer list to variadic function*" as I would have expected, since  there is no type for the compound literal. This is missing at least `(char[])` and `(int[])`, somewhere. And frankly: just don't.

Comment: @dhke I don't know why there is an error in function call f() in main? I have updated the variable definitions.

Comment: @dhke `(GH)` more likely.

Comment: @display_error How does the compiler know `{4,{'1','2','3','4'}, ..., ..., ... }` is a `GH`? You need to tell it...

Comment: @Seb I have updated th main function, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Way too much stuff in question..

Comment: @display_error That's not an answer to my question. You need to tell the compiler the type of your compound literals. Additionally, if you don't understand the error message you should quote it and ask a question about the part(s) you don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some spare time ...

Consider this main:

```
int main()
{
    char info[] = {'1','2','3','4'};
   GH gh1 = { .n = 4, 
              .info = (void*)info, 
              .am = {{0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}}};
   GH gh2 = { .n = 4, 
              .info = (void*)info,
              .am = {{1,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,1}}};

    printGraph(&gh1);

   return 0;
}
```

and this print function:

```
void printGraph(GH *g)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("n = %d\n",g->n);
    printf("info = ");
    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", *((char*)*g->info)+i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<g->n;i++,printf("\n"))
       for(j=0;j<g->n;j++)
          printf(" %2d",g->am[i][j]);
}
```

Both work and produce this output:

```
n = 4
info = 1 2 3 4 
  0  1  1  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0
```

However, when using your f function

```
GH* res=f(2,gh1,gh2);
```

you get segmentation fault.

I don't know what you are trying to calculate, but the problem is not the print function.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Your code sample gives an error "expected expression before '{' token".